# Need to know what 12 is in binary

Tags: binary, numbers, decimal

I tried to do it manually and I got the answer: 1101, but I don't know whether it's right or not.
Is it right? Thanks before

Comment: Googling the words `12 in binary` will even give you this answer. Also protip: anything ending in 1 will be odd

Comment: My -1. This is an easily researchable question which you've clearly not done. Besides, the LSB (right-most) bit has a alue of 1, while every other digit represents an even number. Therefore, any number with the LSB set ***must*** be odd.

Comment: The bit 0 (the least significant bit) is '1', which means odd. This should give you a clue.

Comment: This is a programming stack.  Try writing a program to do it.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111928/is-there-a-printf-converter-to-print-in-binary-format

Comment: Thanks Mr enhzflep, -18 would be more appropriate because I'm very dumb. I'm still learning.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. This is 13. (1101)_2 = (1 * 8 + 1 * 4 + 0 * 2 + 1 * 1)_10 = (13)_10

Answer (score 0):

12 is 1100.

8+4+0+0

You can find many tools on internet.

Answer (score 0):

Thats 13... anything ending with a 1 will be an odd number

**8421**
 *1100*

Answer (score 0):

nope, for (12) in decimal , its (1100) in binary !